# Change ordering of drops downs on Magento product view

Tags: php, magento, drop-down-menu, product

I am building a store based on Magento. I have a few configurable products that have three or four dropdowns. I want to change the order they are displayed on the front end but can't figure it out.

Is there a place I can change the order of the drop downs in the Magento admin or do I need to do some coding? If so, where do I start?

Here is a link to one of the configurable products: http://www.clearwatercarbonfund.org/large-wedding.html

It is still in development so don't mind all the other bad looking stuff.

Thanks!

Chuck

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the order in which the drop-down menus are displayed:

1. Click *Edit* next to the configurable product.
2. Go to the *Associated Products* tabs.
3. Under *Super product attributes configuration*, click and drag the orange double-arrows to re-order them.
4. Click on the orange *Save* button at the top.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]